# Gromov-Witten theory over any field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11716/mirror-symmetry-mod-p-physics-mod-p), VA. said the stack $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}(X,\beta)$ has been constructed over $\mathbb{Z}$. I can not find anything about it but I am quite interested in it. Is there any explicit reference about the construction?